# How do I use one SetUpTestFixture for mutiple classes?

Tags: c#, nunit

Ok so I have the following code, that I want to run only once. I want it to setup at the very beggining of all of the testfixtures I run and once at the end.

```
 [RequiresSTA]
    class Prepare
    {
        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            IE Window = new IE("http://www.google.com");
        }

        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            IE Window = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("Google"));
            Window.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I have multiple classes in my project in the same namespace, lets call them Class1 - 4. I want to set it up so when I run these tests, Prepare only gets called *once*. Example:

**Running 3 + 4:**

```
Prepare Setup
     Run3
     Run4
Prepare Teardown
```

**Running 1 - 4:**

```
Prepare Setup
     Run1
     Run2
     Run3
     Run4
Prepare Teardown
```

Right now Prepare initiates each time a set begins and then concludes each time they end. How can I make it contiuos until all tests in that namespace have been ran?

Answer (score 1):

You can use inheritance for this. You can create a base class that all tests inherit from, and in the base class you can put your setups.

You have to be careful in doing this though. This will mask the setup to anybody who is looking at just the subclass. Unless you override the setup and at least call `base.Setup` in every class.

However, this will only help with code reuse. I do not believe that this will work as you want, and should not. This setup is supposed to run once for every test class. In your unit tests you should not have dependencies on previous tests, so if you NEED this then you might want to re-look at your tests. They should work on their own without any previous tests having to have run. If you do that, then having each class set up its own fixture should not be a problem.

The only way around this would be to have all your tests in one fixture, which, again would be bad test design.

**UPDATE**

It does appear that you can use the [SetupFixture](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4) attribute on a global class that will run for the entire assembly. As stated above, though, use this very carefully as you typically do not want shared state in unit tests.

Something noteworthy to pull from the above link is this:

> Only one SetUpFixture should be created in a given namespace. A
>   SetUpFixture outside of any namespace provides SetUp and TearDown for
>   the entire assembly.

Comment: This Prepare class is my base class, each of my classes do inherit this class, but they run the setups each time instead of just once. Could you possibly provide an example? Maybe I am not understanding what you're saying.

Comment: @Emerica. I just appended to more directly answer your question. Please refresh and re-read

Comment: I mostly only want them to all setup with the same browser instance. Each test has their own setups aswell, but I want to reuse the browser thats all.

Comment: @Emerica. Why, are you having a problem?

Comment: Becasue each time a test closes it closes the browser, and I want to be able to close the browser when all tests are finished. Is there a way I can check if the browser has been inactive and close it?

Comment: Not within the tests, unless you create some kind of sequential dependency b/c, again, tests run in their own sandbox (for a reason). And, the sequential dependency is a bad idea because it makes your tests brittle (what if a new person comes and adds something out of order) Again, just let each one open/close. Maybe you are looking for integration testing, though? For that, I would suggest something like Specflow.

Comment: Well it would have nothing to do with running things out of order, each test has its own personal setup I just want to reuse the browser instance. The browser instance itself should have no weight on the fragility of the tests. It is just a window. If theres one there, use it, if not make a new one. I just don't want to be opening windows becasue you have a small chance that it will fail to initialize with WatiN.

Comment: @Emerica. Well, I decided to do some more looking, and it DOES appear that you can create a global class. See my updated answer

Comment: Yeah, it says entire assembly, but I tried that already and it still runs it for each set of tests individually. Maybe its just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an Assembly setup fixture would be the best way.

```
    //This class does not have a namespace on purpose, do not add one.
  [SetUpFixture]
  public class AssemblySetupFixture
  {
    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTestSuite()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Setting up Test Assembly Fixture");
     // Kill all web server instances and then restart them
        WebServerHelper.StopAll(); 
        WebServerHelper.StartAll();
       DatabaseHelper.RestoreDefaultDatabases();
     }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDownTestSuite()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Tearing down Assembly Fixture");
        WebServerHelper.StopAll();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, I did try this. Assemblies with no Namespace become universal setup/teardowns. Still ran individually at the begginging and end of each test. I am starting to think there is no solution to do exactly what I need.

Comment: That's strange, I've used this on multiple projects and its always worked. What are you using to run the tests?